# Custom post type archive pagination problem with tax_query and pre_get_posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem with the pagination on the custom archive page.

1. I have filter form which is sending the $_POST object with taxonomy parameters which were chosen to the same custom archive page
2. I'm catching this $_POST in 'pre_get_posts' function only for my custom post archive page like that:

```
    function my_query_by_selected_networks( $query ) {

        $paged = get_query_var('paged', 1);

        if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'gallery' ) ) {

            $query->set( 'paged', $paged );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '9' );

            if ( isset( $_POST['filters'] ) ) {

                $tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' ) ?: array();

                $tax_query['relation'] = 'OR';

                if ( isset( $_POST['filters']['year'] ) ) {
                    $tax_query[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'year',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array($_POST['filters']['year'])
                    );
                };

                if ( isset( $_POST['filters']['sport'] ) ) {
                    $tax_query[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'sport',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array($_POST['filters']['sport'])
                    );
                };

                $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

            }
        }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_query_by_selected_networks' );
```

After choosing the filter position in archive page the first page is working perfect but the next one is reset the wp_query.

**I made the tests on $wp_query:**

On the first archive page after choose filter position I have :

```
object(WP_Tax_Query)[6090]
  public 'queries' => 
    array (size=3)
      'relation' => string 'OR' (length=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'taxonomy' => string 'year' (length=4)
          'terms' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'field' => string 'slug' (length=4)
          'operator' => string 'IN' (length=2)
          'include_children' => boolean true
      1 => 
        array (size=5)
          'taxonomy' => string 'sport' (length=5)
          'terms' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'field' => string 'slug' (length=4)
          'operator' => string 'IN' (length=2)
          'include_children' => boolean true
  public 'relation' => string 'OR' (length=2)
  protected 'table_aliases' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'yi_term_relationships' (length=21)
  public 'queried_terms' => 
    array (size=2)
      'year' => 
        array (size=2)
          'terms' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'field' => string 'slug' (length=4)
      'sport' => 
        array (size=2)
          'terms' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'field' => string 'slug' (length=4)
  public 'primary_table' => string 'yi_posts' (length=8)
  public 'primary_id_column' => string 'ID' (length=2)
```

**BUT after going to the second page I see:**

```
object(WP_Tax_Query)[6090]
  public 'queries' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'relation' => string 'AND' (length=3)
  protected 'table_aliases' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'queried_terms' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'primary_table' => string 'yi_posts' (length=8)
  public 'primary_id_column' => string 'ID' (length=2)
```

And every post is visible.

I checked every article but I didn't find the solutions.

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Instead of hooks try to create a custom archive page. Learn the WordPress template hierarchy. 1) https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates 2) https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ 3) https://wphierarchy.com/

Comment: It's a custom archive page, read my question one more time, please :) I know these URLs - thank you but it's not an answer ...

Comment: Check `$_POST['filters']` value in pages other than the first page